# SSH fails when using wired connection

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn

I'm not all that informed about details of SSH and I'm having an issue where when I switch from wireless internet to wired I can't SSH to an EC2 instance as I normally can.  I get the "ssh: Could not resolve hostname" error. I need to have my VPN on when I SSH to these instances.  The issue happens on some but not all instances.  Some instances I can SSH to when I'm connected both wirelessly and via a wired connection.

I'm looking for ideas for what to look into to possibly fix, thanks for any help!

Comment: You have a DNS problem for the wired connection.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley , if there is anything you could provide I could look at to help try to troubleshoot (general ways to diagnose the configurations in order to attempt to try to fix) I would be very thankful.  I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Google search. Also, edit your question with details on your configuration.